# Intersect multiple collection rows with respect to an anchor column

Tags: python, mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo

I am having N collections of different sizes, e.g., `Collection 1` and `Collection 2`. Is there an efficient way to keep the rows with the same `source` id value along with the corresponding `target` ids in the following way?

```
--Collection 1
`source` `target_1`
34        5
45        9
22        2
22        7     <--- not unique source id



--Collection 2
`source` `target_2`
34        23
25        9
22        8
17        99


--Result
`source` `target_1` `target_2`
34        5          23
22        2          8
22        7          8
```

**EDIT1:**

What I have so far is

```
pipeline = [{'$lookup': {'from': 'Collection 2', 'localField': 'source', 'foreignField': 'source', 'as': 'source'}}]
for doc in (db['Collection 1'].aggregate(pipeline)): 
    print(doc)
```

and I am getting in my dataset,

```
{'_id': ObjectId('someCode'), 'source': [], 'target_1': 520838}
{'_id': ObjectId('someCode'), 'source': [{'_id': ObjectId('someCode'), 'target_2': 62483, 'source': 38758}, {'_id': ObjectId('someCode'), 'target_1': 62483, 'source': 38758}], 'target_1': 68099}
```

Any suggestions please to improve the query in order to have the behavior given in the example?

**EDIT2:**

After `@AlexBlex` comments I have

```
pipeline = [{'$lookup': {'from': 'Collection 2', 'localField': 'source', 'foreignField': 'source', 'as': 'source'}},{'$project': {"aligned._id": 0, "aligned.en": 0}]
    for doc in (db['Collection 1'].aggregate(pipeline)): 
        print(doc)
```

which returns

```
{'_id': ObjectId('somecode'), 'source': 38758, 'target_1': 68099, 'aligned': {'target_2': 62483}}
```

can we further remove the `aligned` tag to obtain

```
{'_id': ObjectId('somecode'), 'source': 38758, 'target_1': 68099, 'target_2': 62483}
```

**EDIT3:**

After `@AlexBlex` comments I have

```
pipeline = [{'$lookup': {'from': 'Collection 2', 'localField': 'source', 'foreignField': 'source', 'as': 'source'}},{"$project": {'source': 1, 'target_1': 1, 'target_2': "$aligned.target_2"}]
    for doc in (db['Collection 1'].aggregate(pipeline)): 
        print(doc)
```

which returns

```
{'_id': ObjectId('somecode'), 'source': 9770, 'target_1': 4802, 'target_2': 180}
{'_id': ObjectId('somecode'), 'source': 9770, 'target_1': 4802, 'target_2': 180}
{'_id': ObjectId('somecode'), 'source': 9770, 'target_1': 4802, 'target_2': 180}
{'_id': ObjectId('somecode'), 'source': 9770, 'target_1': 4802, 'target_2': 5689}
{'_id': ObjectId('somecode'), 'source': 124, 'target_1': 78, 'target_2': 250}
{'_id': ObjectId('somecode'), 'source': 124, 'target_1': 78, 'target_2': 250}
{'_id': ObjectId('somecode'), 'source': 124, 'target_1': 78, 'target_2': 250}
```

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/

Comment: @AlexBlex thanks for the response. Is it possible to provide an example?  I am not aware of  `pymondo` queries especially when they are a little more complicated, at least for me.

Comment: I trust you will find plenty of examples if you search `pymongo` instead. e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41992885/pymongo-how-to-match-on-lookup

Comment: @AlexBlex I am trying a query, see edit, but I have some problems. Any suggestions please?

Comment: `'as': 'source'` overwrites `source` field in the original document from Collection 1. The output says there are no matching documents to target_1 520838, and there are 2 matching documents for target_1 68099. It also says the Collection_2 has documents with target_1 and no target_2 unless it is a typo. I reckon `'en': 38758` meant to be `'source': 38758`.

Comment: To exclude results with no matches use $match stage https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/ to filter out documents with empty arrays. To handle non-unique ids in Collection 2 use $unwind https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/ to duplicate documents for each item in the array.

Comment: @AlexBlex thanks again, I think I am close. The `$unwind` solved the no matched results, please correct me If I am missing something. Also, helped to unfold the dictionaries inside the results defined by `as`. Can we further proceed to keep only the `target_2` and remove the `dict` structure? Please see relevant `Edit2`.

Comment: yes, change $project stage to `{'$project': {"target_2": "$aligned.target_2"}}` Docs are here https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#include-computed-fields

Comment: @AlexBlex Worked for `{"$project": {'source': 1, 'target_1': 1, 'target_2': "$aligned.target_2"}}`, taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30888282/how-to-remove-duplicate-values-inside-a-list-in-mongodb). But there are duplicates. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: but you wanted duplicates for non-unique ids, right?

Comment: @AlexBlex yes but some results are exactly the same, please see Edit3. The first four results are fine but the last three results are exact, which is a redundancy.  Can we avoid this?

Comment: Ok, it is database's mistake. There are dublicates.

Comment: I am trying to eliminate dublicates with `$group` using ` {''$group': {'_id': {'source': '$source', 'target_1': '$target_1', 'target_2': '$target_1'}}}`but is very slow. All fields have index.  Is this approach correct? If yes can we make it faster?

Comment: Indexes work in very limited cases in aggregation https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/#std-label-aggregation-pipeline-operators-and-performance Dedup first, then lookup. It should speed up a little. Don't expect miracles unless you have very low cardinality

Comment: @AlexBlex sorry again, I am trying `db['collection'].ensure_index([("target", pymongo.ASCENDING), ("unique", 1), ("dropDups", 1)])` in order to remove duplicates but does not work. Could you please give a suggestion to remove duplicates?

Comment: dropDups is a ghost. It was removed in v3 many years ago. Use grouping like you did, just move it to the first stage of the pipeline so you can benefit from indexes. For the best performance create a compound index with all 3 fields as mongo rarely use index intersection. Or write a script to sanitise your data and remove duplicated documents from collections for good.